# custom init for UITableView connected as IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can't seem to find in the Apple Developer documentation on how to properly subclass a `UITableView`. Specifically, I have a custom table view that is connected to an IBOutlet.

I am wanting to initialize it in a view controller and pass the data source in its initializer.

I have seen many questions about subclassed `UITableViewCell`s but no much about subclassed `UITableView`.

Comment: You should probably go about it in the programmatic way as Frankenstein stated below. But honestly, based on your description of why you want a subclassed UITableView, it seems a bit meaningless unless there is some more custom implementation. Assigning a delegate and datasource is 2 lines in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sub-class `UITableView` just as you sub-class anything else in Swift.

```
class MyTableView: UITableView {
    //...
}
```

But, if you want to create a custom initializer and "use it" you've do add it programmatically without the storyboard. The storyboard uses `init?(coder:` method to initialize the tableView.

```
class MyTableView: UITableView {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { // storyboard uses this method
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

If you want to use custom initializer then you should use the programmatic approach.